# jQuery - How to get Facebook redirect to profile page?

Tags: jquery

Okay, so I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out.

When someone visits my website, I want for them to be able to click a link and in the process of using just jQuery (via AJAX request or other), or Javascript, figure out what their profile URL is.

**Here is the scenario:**

Bobby visits my site. I know Bobby is a little below average intelligence, so asking him to visit Facebook, make sure he's logged in, and then click on his name to see his Profile page (which you can get to by visiting `facebook.com/profile.php`), is a difficult task. Because now I need for Bobby to COPY that URL and put it into a little, tiny textbox on my page. And Bobby's going to have a rough time doing that...

**Here is the process:**

When you visit the link I provided above, if you're currently logged into Facebook, it's going to magically (through a redirect) send you to your own Profile page. (Give it a shot... I'll wait.) THAT URL is exactly what I need to get.

So, for instance, if your Profile page is really `facebook.com/joe.d.blow`, and you're currently logged into Facebook, and you visit the link I presented, you'll get sent to that page... the `facebook.com/joe.d.blow` page.

**Why am I looking for this?**

It's simple, really... I have a need to show people their Facebook pictures through capturing their personal URL. And you can't call up JSON information without the user ID or the USERNAME, which I could capture if they provided their personal URL.

**What have I tried:**

• Opening a new window. This won't work because too many people have
   pop-up blockers, and asking them to allow my pop-up is not frugal.

• A few AJAX calls to Facebook without much luck. I was just trying
   to find the header redirect information.

• Anything with an iFrame won't work, since Facebook crushes all
   frames. (Found that out here on SO. Yeah... I search stuff.)

PHP is out of the question, since the cookies are probably maintaining the information client-side that would lead to the Profile page in question. So, I'm stuck with either Javascript, jQuery, or telling Bobby to wise up and learn the interwebs.

SO folks, you're my final hope. (This site is like my bible when it comes to programming.)

Comment: Another option: implement facebook login in your site

Comment: I had considered that, but then I'd feel like I was building up a barn when all I needed was a doghouse. You know what I mean? Too much extra stuff when all I need is for the client to get me that URL without all their extra effort.

Comment: You can't emulate browsing on the client side. Also how will you find out `if you're currently logged into Facebook`, if you are not using Facebook's OAuth or a FB plugin? So I second @koala_dev...

Comment: @Balint: You must have read this wrong, because it's saying that the client would be the one browsing, not the site I'm creating, thus no real emulation of anything.

But I digress... I just realized that all of this is squashed because of XSS, anyhow, since you can't even get a URL from a simple pop-up window without it throwing a bunch of errors. If you can't even do that, there must be no way to dynamically find out a URL for a site when the client clicks on something.

Comment: No, I read it well :) But you need a URL after a redirect and a click, which is something I was describing. The multi-tab/window approach is a security issue, that is why was OAuth created with all the callbacks...